# Parse error in mysql query

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is the mysql query:

```
$data = "SELECT course_name, studentAttendance.course_course_code 
FROM login, course, staff, studentAttendance 
WHERE studentAttendance.staff_staff_id = staff.staff_id 
AND studentAttendance.course_course_code = course.course_code 
AND staff.login_login_id = login.login_id 
AND login.login_id = $_SESSION['login_user'] 
GROUP BY studentAttendance.course_course_code";
```

The error is said to be:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
(T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\attendance_system\dashboard-lecturer.php on line 267
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below query,

```
"SELECT course_name, studentAttendance.course_course_code FROM login, course, staff, studentAttendance 
WHERE studentAttendance.staff_staff_id = staff.staff_id 
AND studentAttendance.course_course_code = course.course_code 
AND staff.login_login_id = login.login_id 
AND login.login_id = '".$_SESSION['login_user']."' 
GROUP BY studentAttendance.course_course_code";
```

Answer (score 1):

When using an array index variable inside of double quotes, you should put the variable inside {}.  So use {$_SESSION['login_user']} instead.

Comment: Or this way.. '".$_SESSION['login_user']."'  @Ellie

Comment: Either way works, I just think using {} looks cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You need curly brackets for array access in double quoted strings.
Try this

```
{$_SESSION['login_user']}
```